# How to Show/Hide a block of text with ruby on rails based on a button click or link click

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to ruby on rails and i'm trying to figure out how to hide/show a block of text based on a clicking a button or a link.

I followed the example in this link:

http://www.davidthomas.net.au/2009/09/ruby-on-rails-howto-showhide-div/comment-page-1/#comment-441

However, there are three problems I've experienced

1. I'm not sure how to apply the logic to a button/link instead of a check box, or if its possible.  The problem is I don't know how to associate the click on the button or link to the action within the observer.  Maybe i'm not understanding the syntax.  With the Example, the :on => :selected gives the observer an parameter to work with in the accepted_terms method.
2. I'm currently using eclipse with ruby on rails(aptana) and can only see the code working sometimes on the browser built into eclipse and sometimes not (have to reload the page to get the check box working). With normal browser like Chrome, clicking the check box has no effect what so ever. Is there some setting i'm doing wrong? Browser setting?
3. Is there an easier way to do this then using the Observer_field method?

Thanks for any advise or links to examples that will help,
D

Comment: Are you talking about clicking an element and text/elements/.. appear? Like the commentfield here in SO?

Comment: Are you familiar with jQuery or any other javascript library?

Comment: Dr Colossos,
Yeah i'm talking about clicking an element and test/elements appear like the comment field.

Do you know how it's implmented or any links to help?


Shirpad K,

I've heard about it, but i'm not familiar with JQUery or javascript.  Well, I'll prob end up using JQuery or javascript since it seems like thats the only way you can do it.  Any suggestion on what methods i should be using in JQuery or javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Send ajax request and update the particular area using partials.

like that

```
render :partial => "partial_name", :layout => false
```

partial name starts with underscore

Comment: Let me try that.  I didn't use the :layout => false in my code.  Is that necessary?